# F# denies existence of a constructor (probably type-constraint related)

Tags: f#, signature-files

On the following code, F sharp says: module xyz requires a value `new : (IBlah<'a> * 'b) -> test<'a, 'b>')`

I have tried supplying that exact constructor as an explicit new but it did not seem to help, though Intellisense though the type was the same. I expect I have somehow got the constraints wrong. Could someone please tell me what to change so the code compiles (without removing the constraints)? Many thanks.

First the fsi file:

```
module xyz

type IBlah<'a> =
    abstract something : 'a -> 'a

type IHuha =
    abstract something : unit -> unit

type test<'a, 'b when 'a :> IHuha and 'b : comparison> =
    new : (IBlah<'a> * 'b) -> test<'a, 'b>
    member huha : unit -> unit
```

The fs file is:

```
module xyz

type IBlah<'a> =
    abstract something : 'a -> 'a

type IHuha =
    abstract something : unit -> unit

type test<'a, 'b when 'a :> IHuha and 'b : comparison> (x:IBlah<'a>, y:'b) =

    member x.huha () = printf "%O" x
```

Comment: Is the first code snippet meant to be a signature file?

Comment: Yes, sorry for not making that clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the signature file is describing a constructor which takes a single value of type tuple

```
(IBlah<'a> * 'b)
```

The actual constructor though takes 2 values of type `IBlah<'a>` and `'b`.  Speculating that the .fs implementation is the one you want.  If so then just remove the extra parens from the .fsi file

```
new : IBlah<'a> * 'b -> test<'a, 'b>
```

Comment: @JoeHuha i only knew the answer because I made the exact same mistake at one point :)